# Use a unique javaScript and CSS for multiple components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a styled-select dropdown menu, and I created it's own `.css` and `.js`.
This is what happens when I use only one dropdown menu in a page, which works fine as expected:

[jsFiddle OK](https://jsfiddle.net/zerwfhoe/1/)

Instead when I use two dropdown menu it's a mess, and it's normal, because my `.js` file will do it's functions to all those dropdown menu which exists on the page. This is how it appears when I use two dropdown menu with the same `.js` and `.css` files:

[jsFiddle NOT OK](https://jsfiddle.net/L09fwp7c/3/)

Now my questions is how can I use the same `.js` and `.css` files for multiple dropdown's which all of them act as expected?

```js
 
 $(function () {
     $('.styled-select select').hide();
     
     $("select#elem").val('2'); 
     $('.styled-select div').html($('.styled-select select option:selected').text());
     
     $('.styled-select div').click(function () {
         $('.styled-select select').show();
         $('.styled-select select').attr('size', 5);
         $('.styled-select select').focus();
     });

     $('.styled-select select').click(function () {
         $('.styled-select div').html($('.styled-select select option:selected').text());
         $('.styled-select select').hide();
     });
     $('.styled-select select').focusout(function () {
         $('.styled-select select').hide();
     });

 });
```

```css
    .styled-select select {
        position: absolute;
        background: transparent;
        width: 420px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
        color: black;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 4;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -o-appearance: none;
        z-index: 1;
        outline: none;
        left: -7px;
    }
    .styled-select {
        background: url('../img/campaignSelector.png') no-repeat right;
        background-color: white;
        width: 420px;
        height: 42px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
        background-position: 97% 50%;
    }
    .styled-select option {
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: 3px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        display: none; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div style="width:800px; height: 600px; background: grey;">
        <div class="styled-select" style="left:-250px; top:90px; width:200px;">
            <div style="font-size:18px; height:42px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 4px;"></div>
            <select id="" name="" style="margin:0 0 0 5px; border: none;" onblur="this.size=0; width:200px;" onchange="this.size=0;">
                <option value="0">Marco P</option>
                <option value="1">Marco F</option>
                <option value="2">Daniele</option>
                <option value="3">Cristina</option>
                <option value="4">Angine</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="styled-select" style=" width:200px; left:50px; top:48px;">
            <div style="font-size:18px; height:42px; position:relative; top:10px; left: 4px;"></div>
            <select id="" name="" style="margin:0 0 0 5px; border: none;" onblur="this.size=0; width:200px;" onchange="this.size=0;">
                <option value="0">ReshaD</option>
                <option value="1">Rasheed</option>
                <option value="2">Reza</option>
                <option value="3">Davin</option>
                <option value="4">Ariya</option>
            </select>
        </div> 

    </div>
```

Comment: Your Question - No Code - Not OK.

Comment: @PraveenKumar all the codes are in the jsfiddle. should I include them here also??

Comment: Yes, buddy... Coz there are lot of people, who just have StackOverflow access but no access to JSBin or JSFiddle. :) You can press `Ctrl + M` while answering to bring something similar to JSFiddle. Kindly consider that.

Comment: Man, you have some errors: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Kindly check. It doesn't work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar now could you please cancel your vote down? because some people will vote down for already voted down questions. ;) thanks

Comment: The moment I said awesome, I have removed my downvote.

Comment: Don't worry. It will go off soon. But please answer my comment.

Comment: @PraveenKumar where are these errors? could you please mention that, so I will check them

Comment: Use console to check them. F12 brings you dev tools in Chrome, Firefox and all other good browsers. There you can find the console and it has lot of errors.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am in MacOSX and my F12 will volume up. Thanks for your help, problem solved with Rory's answer :)

Comment: Man, below is an awesome answer from my friend. I guess that should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work for multiple instances of the `.styled-select` container you need to use `$(this)` to reference the element which is raising the event and then use `closest()` to get the nearest parent `.style-select`. From there you can use `find()` to get the required element. Try this:

```
$('.styled-select select').hide();
$("select#elem").val('2');

$('.styled-select div').each(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
    $(this).html($container.find('select option:selected').text());
});

$('.styled-select div').click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
    $container.find('select').show().attr('size', 5).focus();
});

$('.styled-select select').click(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
    var text = $container.find('select option:selected').text();
    $container.find('div').html(text);
    $container.find('select').hide();
});

$('.styled-select select').focusout(function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('.styled-select');
    $container.find('select').hide();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L09fwp7c/5/)

Comment: I guess this could have been closed as a dupe right?

Comment: Thankssss ! worked ! I will click as solved in 5 minutes.